# How to write Mybatis XML Mapper with two parameter (1st is List<String>, 2nd is Long)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

My current mybatis `mapper.xml` is

```
  <select id="batchSelect" resultMap="ResultMap">
    select id, user_id, mall_id, log, log_type
    from user_log
    where user_id in (
    <foreach collection="userList" index="index" item="item" separator=",">
      #{item,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    </foreach>
    ) and mall_id = #{1}
  </select>
```

the java `Mapper.java` is

```
List<UserLog> batchSelect(List<String> userList, Long mallId);
```

When I start spring-boot service, the exception is:

```
exception: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'userList' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, param1, param2]
```

How can I write this correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the annonation `@Param`

```
List<UserLog> batchSelect(@Param("userList")List<String> userList, @Param("mailId")Long mallId);

<select id="batchSelect" resultMap="ResultMap">
    select id, user_id, mall_id, log, log_type
    from user_log
    where user_id in (
    <foreach collection="userList" index="index" item="item" separator=",">
      #{item,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    </foreach>
    ) and mall_id = #{mailId}
  </select>
```

Comment: OK I will try this

Answer (score 0):

actually, mybatis-generator supprot `selectByExample`, `updateByExample`, they all support `where in` clause.

this is my final choice